# Mimic self-insert-command with insert/insert-char?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, insert, self-insert-command

Due to various/extensive remappings I insert symbols with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> inserts a left parenthesis `(`. This works fine with the remappings and the insert/insert-commands, however, modes such as smartparens do not catch this. In my example hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> with spartparens should insert a pair of parentheses `()` instead of a single one (which works using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>). I suspect that the problem is due to using `insert`/`insert-char` instead of `self-insert-command` so the mode does not see/register the event. I wonder if anyone has any idea for a fix?

This my setup code for reference, essentially a loop over a macro that sets up a global keybinding for `C-[unshifted char]` to `[corresponding shifted char]`:

```
; Bind Ctrl as shift for symbols.
(defun my-bind-symbols-to-crtl ()
  (interactive)
  (let ( (chars (split-string
                 "~1234567890-=;']\\,./" ""))
         (shifted-chars (split-string
                         "`!@#$%^&*()_+:\"}|<>?" ""))
         (char "") (shifted-char "") )
    (while chars
      (setq char (pop chars))
      (setq shifted-char (pop shifted-chars))
      (when (> (length char) 0)
        (global-set-key (kbd (concat "C-" char)) (eval(macroexpand `(insert-key-macro ,shifted-char)))) ) )))

(defmacro insert-key-macro (in)
  `(lambda () (interactive) (insert ,in)))
(my-bind-symbols-to-crtl)
(global-set-key (kbd "H-[") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "{")))
(define-key input-decode-map (kbd "C-[") (kbd "H-["))
```

Comment: Welcome.  Can you provide some code showing how you implement this?

Comment: One alternative would be to use `function-key-map` to translate `C-9` to `S-9` and then let nature take its course.

Comment: `(define-key input-decode-map (kbd (concat "C-" char)) (kbd shifted-char))))`

Comment: Just so you know, smartparens does it's work with a function in  `post-self-insert-hooks`, You could just `(run-hooks 'post-self-insert-hooks)` after inserting. But I think @Lindydancer's solution is the better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys defined by `global-set-key` are shadowed by any local binding. In your case using `key-translation-map` seems more appropriate. Also, when defining keys, you can use a string (interpreted as a keyboard macro) instead of a command. This would greatly simplify your code:

```
(defun my-bind-symbols-to-crtl ()
  (cl-mapcar
   (lambda (char shifted-char)
     (define-key key-translation-map (kbd (concat "C-" char))
       shifted-char))
   (split-string
    "~1234567890-=;']\\,./" "" t)
   (split-string
    "`!@#$%^&*()_+:\"}|<>?" "" t)))

(my-bind-symbols-to-crtl)
```